# Using REGEXP_EXTRACT doesn't give the expected result - Hive

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive

I am trying to use `REGEXP_EXTRACT` function in Hive to get the required string from a column. The data in the column is in the form:

`words\more_words`

I need to extract the portion of the string after `\`. I tried doing something like this:

`SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT('words\more_words','(.*)(\\+)(.*)',3) -> returns nothing`

`SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT('words\more_words','.*(\\+)(.*)',2) -> returns nothing`

`SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT('words\more_words','\w+(\\+)(\w+)',2)-> returns nothing`

`SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT('words\more_words','\\+(\w+)',1) -> returns nothing`

I've verified that all the above Regular expressions match `words\more_words` on `regex101.com`(except for the last regex which matches `\more_words`). but, I am completely clueless why hive isn't giving the desired result.

I wasn't sure if I was doing something wrong. So, for verification, I did this:

`SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT('words\more_words','.*\\.*',0) -> returns 'wordsmore_words'`

Not sure why `\` was removed from the result. Technically, the regex should match the whole string and result should be the whole string, right?

How do I extract the portion of the String after `\` ? any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: A single literal backslash is defined with `'\\'`. In a regex, double literal backslashes can be used to match a literal backslash. So, try `SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT('words\\more_words','.*\\\\+(.*)',1)`. Note that `'words\\more_words'` defines a `words\more_words` string.

Comment: It works! although I don't understand the concept behind it..can you post an answer and elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single *literal backslash* is defined with `'\\'`. That is, if a string contains `\`, you should use two backslashes in the string literal, `'\\'`.

In a regex, double literal backslashes can be used to match a literal backslash. A string pattern `\\` should be written as `'\\\\'` in order to match a single literal backsalsh.

Use

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT('words\\more_words','.*\\\\+(.*)',1)
```

Note that `'words\\more_words'` is a string literal that defines a `words\more_words` literal string.

**Pattern details**

- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\\\\+` - 1 or more literal `\` chars
- `(.*)` - capturing group #1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible (that you return with the help of the last `1` argument to the `REGEXP_EXTRACT` function).